# Using regex and conditional expression at the same time in Terraform

Tags: regex, terraform

I want to write a conditional expression in Terraform something like this:

```
name = regex("p[1-9]+", my_input) ? "production" : "testing"
```

However, this does not work because regex function:

1. Returns the matching string rather than true/false
2. If my_input does not match the pattern, an error is thrown

What is the correct way to achieve this in Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`can`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/can) like this:

```
name = can(regex("p[1-9]+", my_input)) ? "production" : "testing"
```

---

Here is a simple input/output example:

```
$ terraform console
> can(regex("p[1-9]+", "pab1")) ? "production" : "testing"
"testing"
> can(regex("p[1-9]+", "p123")) ? "production" : "testing"
"production"
>
```